# when change background color of a link adding a class the class is not removed in other links and the link doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of sidebar:

```
<nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
    <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
        <div class="nav" id="mianav">
            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">
                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                Dashboard
            </a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'agenda' %}">
                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></div>
                Agenda
            </a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-database"></i></div>
                CRUD App
            </a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></div>
                File Upload
            </a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullseye"></i></div>
                Ajax Crud
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is the javascript function that i use to change the bacgound link when is clicked adding a class. But the class of the other links is not removed and the link doesn't work.

```
$('#mianav a').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('miaactive').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('miaactive');
                localStorage.setItem('target', $(this).data("target"));
            });
            var target = localStorage.getItem('target');
            !target || $('a[data-target="' + target + '"]').addClass('miaactive').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('miaactive');
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the existing class from an element using it's class name as selector.

```
$('.miaactive').removeClass('miaactive');  
$(this).addClass('miaactive');
```

The above line will remove the class from existing and add class to the clicked one.

```js
$('#mianav a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.miaactive').removeClass('miaactive');
  $(this).addClass('miaactive');
  localStorage.setItem('target', $(this).attr('id'));
});
var target = localStorage.getItem('target');
if(target) {
  $(`a[id="${target}"]`).addClass('miaactive');
}
```

```css
.miaactive {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
  <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
    <div class="nav" id="mianav">
      <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
      <a id="one" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
        Dashboard
      </a>
      <a id="two" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'agenda' %}">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></div>
        Agenda
      </a>
      <a id="three" class="nav-link" href="#">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-database"></i></div>
        CRUD App
      </a>
      <a id="four" class="nav-link" href="#">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></div>
        File Upload
      </a>
      <a id="five" class="nav-link" href="#">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullseye"></i></div>
        Ajax Crud
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thx this solve 1 issue but the link doen't work because of e.preventDefault(); and the class is not keeped after a page reload

Comment: @AmedeoDeLongis The solution has been updated. If you provide ids to all of the anchor elements, you may save the id of the clicked anchor element in local storage and apply class to it on page reload based on the id stored in local storage.